# How to change/inverse graph style in excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

Does anyone know how to change graph style from graph 1 into graph 2. I tried to do reverse the axis however still can't get the it. Thanks for the help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plot the first chart (which I assume you know how to do), enter -1 in a cell, copy it, select the x-axis data and Paste Special, Multiply.

Then take your maximum y-value from the original data (say 600), enter that in a cell, copy it, select the x-axis data and Paste Special, Add.